# Cannot assign to read only property 'stopImmediatePropagation' of object

Tags: angular, webpack

After upgrading @angular/platform-browser (and others @angular/xxx) to versione 6.0.4, i've this error at first load of the application and after each first page reload (first F5: error, second F5: work):

> NodeInvocationException: Cannot assign to read only property
>   'stopImmediatePropagation' of object '[object Object]' TypeError:
>   Cannot assign to read only property 'stopImmediatePropagation' of
>   object '[object Object]' at
>   DomEventsPlugin.module.exports../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js.DomEventsPlugin.patchEvent
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:60044:50)
>   at new DomEventsPlugin
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:60031:15)
>   at eval (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:51:25) at _callFactory
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40373:28)
>   at _createProviderInstance$1
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40319:26)
>   at resolveNgModuleDep
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40282:21)
>   at _createClass
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40346:29)
>   at _createProviderInstance$1
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40316:26)
>   at resolveNgModuleDep
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40282:21)
>   at _createClass
>   (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40352:32)

This is the code in my vendor.js where the error is generated:

```
DomEventsPlugin.prototype.patchEvent = function () {
    if (!Event || !Event.prototype) {
        return;
    }
    if (Event.prototype[stopMethodSymbol]) {
        // already patched by zone.js
        return;
    }
    var delegate = Event.prototype[stopMethodSymbol] =
        Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation;
    Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation = function () { <-- ERROR
        if (this) {
            this[stopSymbol] = true;
        }
        // should call native delegate in case
        // in some environment part of the application
        // will not use the patched Event
        delegate && delegate.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

This is my environment

- .NET Core 2.1
- Angular 6.0.4
- Angular/Cli 6.0.8
- Webpack 4.12.0
- aspnet-prerendering 3.0.1
- aspnet-webpack 3.0.0

In dev mode i've the webpack dev middleware active, can the error be related to the time of creation of the vendor? The first load time the application create the vendor, the second time the vendor is taken from the cache:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing action CTAgenda.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CTAgenda)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method CTAgenda.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CTAgenda) - Validation state: Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action method CTAgenda.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CTAgenda), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 0.626ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view Index.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/dist/__webpack_hmr
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action CTAgenda.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CTAgenda) in 1660.2506ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Cannot assign to read only property 'stopImmediatePropagation' of object '[object Object]'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'stopImmediatePropagation' of object '[object Object]'
    at DomEventsPlugin.module.exports../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js.DomEventsPlugin.patchEvent (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:60044:50)
    at new DomEventsPlugin (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:60031:15)
    at eval (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:51:25)
    at _callFactory (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40373:28)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40319:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40282:21)
    at _createClass (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40346:29)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40316:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40282:21)
    at _createClass (I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:40352:32)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExportAsync[T](NodeInvocationInfo invocationInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.InvokeExportAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, String moduleName, String exportNameOrNull, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
   at AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 2
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2035.1489ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operazione di I/O terminata a causa dell'uscita dal thread oppure della richiesta di un'applicazione. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Operazione di I/O terminata a causa dell'uscita dal thread oppure della richiesta di un'applicazione
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 600.0987ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      i ´¢ówdm´¢ú: wait until bundle finished: /dist/__webpack_hmr
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      Node will restart because file changed: I:\Progetti\Platform\Software\CTAgenda\wwwroot\dist\main-client.js
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      webpack built 1c1bbe760c1dbb40f7fd in 72352ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      i ´¢ówdm´¢ú: Hash: 1c1bbe760c1dbb40f7fd
      Version: webpack 4.12.0
      Time: 72352ms
      Built at: 2018-06-12 11:06:08
                   Asset      Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
          main-client.js  1.94 MiB  main-client  [emitted]  main-client
                    0.js  48.5 KiB            0  [emitted]
                    1.js  48.3 KiB            1  [emitted]
      main-client.js.map  34.4 KiB  main-client  [emitted]  main-client
                0.js.map  81 bytes            0  [emitted]
                1.js.map  81 bytes            1  [emitted]
      Entrypoint main-client = main-client.js main-client.js.map
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices[0]
      i ´¢ówdm´¢ú: Compiled successfully.
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Did you update the rxjs library to 6 as well?

Comment: yes, i did: 6.2.0

Comment: I'm also facing the same error the only thing I can suggest is that error could be due to zone.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a global update of all my packages, everything started working again. The same for other users, check [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24407#issuecomment-403304953)

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.7",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
"css": "2.2.3",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
"jquery": "3.3.1",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
"nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
"popper.js": "^1.14.3",
"preboot": "6.0.0-beta.4",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
"rxjs": "^6.2.1",
"stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.7",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.0.7",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.8",
"@types/chai": "4.1.4",
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^10.5.1",
"@types/stacktrace-js": "0.0.32",
"@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"chai": "4.1.2",
"codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
"css-loader": "^0.28.11",
"file-loader": "^1.1.11",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"jasmine": "^3.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "2.0.4",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
"karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
"ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
"protractor": "~5.3.2",
"style-loader": "^0.21.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "^5.10.0",
"typescript": "^2.7.2",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
"url-loader": "^1.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.14.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```html
DomEventsPlugin.prototype.patchEvent = function () {
    if (!Event || !Event.prototype) {
        return;
    }
    if (Event.prototype[stopMethodSymbol]) {
        // already patched by zone.js
        return;
    }
    var delegate = Event.prototype[stopMethodSymbol] =
        Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation;
    Event.prototype[stopMethodSymbol] = function () {  <-- CHANGE
        if (this) {
            this[stopSymbol] = true;
        }
        // should call native delegate in case
        // in some environment part of the application
        // will not use the patched Event
        delegate && delegate.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Comment: I couldn't find any difference between present code and your's can you please tell if you've changed anything to get it working

Comment: @Black Mamba, Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation  change on Event.prototype[stopMethodSymbol]. it helped me

Comment: @BlackMamba, the solution for me works, however I wonder if there is a more robust way, as this implies manually modifying the vendor.js file

Comment: The other solution was there in a GitHub issue which was to download angular universal repo locally and then shift your source there. That worked for me as well. @ghego1